# How to integrate brave zipkins with my services

Tags: java, zipkin

I need to integrate brave zipkins with my services which I have already implemented.  I need a brief idea of how can I get started with this?

Is it enough if I just do `endPointSubmitter.submit("127.0.0.1", 4444, "test-service");` should I just create endpoints and do a submit on these ports?

I have already set ports for my services. And all the services are registered to zookeeper.

Answer (score 0):

Tracing is more than knowing the endpoints of the services. Ex the most important task is timing when something starts and stops (Ex via ServerTracer or indirectly via one of brave's concepts such as ServerRequestAdapter).

It is unclear from your question if you are tracing already and are finding the endpoints are being misreported, or if you aren't actually tracing anything.

Can you clarify what you have setup so far?